# How to get the value of a Controller variable in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I set a variable inside a Controller and I'm trying to just do something as simple as read that variable in the rails console.

I thought about just doing `@test` in the console which is the name of the variable. but it shows as `>null`. When I do puts under where I set the variable it traces out the correct value in my terminal window.

Any ideas what I need to do to get to this variable via the console.

I tried putting the name of the controller first and then .variable but that threw an error

I can see what's inside my models by just using the model name and some attributes like .first and .last

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to instantiate the controller and provide a public accessor to get the value in `rails console`.

If you're trying to debug something, I recommend you check out [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry). It's a Ruby debugging REPL. Do a `require 'pry'` in your controller, and put `binding.pry` somewhere in an action, when you execute that controller method--either interactively in a browser, or via a functional test (I recommend the latter)--it will open the Pry REPL and `@test` will be in scope there.

Check out this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails) for some help using it.

Alternately, just rely on good unit or functional testing. Write a test around the method and add an assertion on `assigns(:@test)` to compare the value to your expectation. Check out the [RSpec controller spec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs).

Comment: So RSpec is another separate gem to rails for testing. Reading up on it right now.

Comment: You can do the same with [Test::Unit](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers), which is the default framework that ships with Rails (or at least used to).